# debugging git bundle (file generated too big)

Tags: git

For some reason, I need to do git bundle

The issue is, for one of my projects)the file ends up being very big. (think like 50M instead of a few k).

**How can I investigate why it is so big?**

The commands line:

```
git bundle create someFile.bundle myBranch origin/myBranch
```

Comment: Do you want to store the entire repository history, or just one or a few recent commits?

Comment: juste the recent commits

Answer (score 0):

To store just a few commits, you must know at least one commit that is in the repository where you want to unbundle the bundle. `origin/master` is a good candidate if the repositories have been cloned from the same upstream. But any commit object ID (SHA1) that is present in both repositories. Then the command is:

```
git bundle create someFile.bundle origin/master..myBranch
```

or (as your post indicates)

```
git bundle create someFile.bundle origin/myBranch..myBranch
```

To repeat: The destination must have the exact commit that is `origin/myBranch` in your repository; it is not enough that they have *some* commit named `origin/myBranch`.

Explanation:

With your command, you have actually packaged the entire history leading up to `myBranch`. The trick to reduce the size is to package just the objects that the other side does not have. For this reason, you pick a commit that is present in the destination, and then you can reduce the history by passing a commit range that ends in your branch tip: `their/commit..myBranch`.